# Linearity of open balls

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, general-topology

I was revising a proof concerning convex sets and in one step it was established the following equality (in the book, a ball of center $x$ and radius $r$ is represented by $x+r\mathbb{B}$, where $\mathbb{B}$ is the ball of radius 1 and center the origin):

$$\alpha x + \beta y +r\mathbb{B}=\alpha (x+r\mathbb{B}) + \beta (y+r\mathbb{B})$$

I can't really see geometrically how this holds. And I am also stuck with its formal proof with the double inclusion by definition of ball. Appreciate any help.

Comment: That doesn't seem true - left side is ball of radius $r$ and right of radius $(\alpha + \beta) r$.

Comment: is there a condition on $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that isn't stated here? Perhaps that  $\alpha + \beta =1$?

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to precise that. Yes, $\alpha + \beta=1$

Comment: @CharlesJA Then add this information to your question.